# After rolling two dice and flipping 12 coins. What is the probability that the # of heads is equal to the sum of the numbers showing on the two dice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, dice

> Suppose we roll two fair six-sided dice and flip 12 coins. What is the probability that the number of heads is equal to the sum of the numbers showing on the two dice?

My solution is:

$$\frac{\binom{12}{2} +\binom{12}{12} + \sum_{i=3}^{11}\binom{12}{i}}{2^{12}\times6^2}$$

Did I get it correct?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. For example, you have $2$ favorable rolls of dice to match $3$ heads.

Comment: @Vasya yea, I just realized I had to add in a factor in the summation that accounts for the number of ways you could get a given sum. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be the sum of the two numbers on the dice.  Then $$\Pr[X = x] = \begin{cases}\frac{6-|x-7|}{36}, & x \in \{2, 3, \ldots, 12\}, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  Let $Y$ be the number of heads flipped out of $12$ coins.  Then $$\Pr[Y = y] = \binom{12}{y} (1/2)^y (1 - 1/2)^{12-y} = \frac{1}{2^{12}} \binom{12}{y}, \quad y \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 12\}.$$
Then the desired probability is $$\Pr[X = Y] = \sum_{x=0}^{12} \Pr[X = x]\Pr[Y = x] = \frac{1}{6^2 2^{12}} \sum_{x=2}^{12} (6 - |7-x|)\binom{12}{x} .$$

Comment: Yea, I needed to add in a factor to consider the number of ways you could sum the dice to get a given number. Thanks